# Loosing serial connection between InSim.NET and arduino

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I've tried to make an application using InSim.NET to redirect outgauge packets from udp to serial port connected with arduino but ive encountered a problem.

After a couple of seconds of correct transmission, connection is lost. 
Numbers in console and display from arduino stop refreshing.
I don't know where the problem is. Please help

This is my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using InSimDotNet.Out;

namespace dotnet
{


    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            SerialPort serialport = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

             serialport.Open();

            // Create OutGauge object with the specified timeout.
            using (OutGauge outgauge = new OutGauge())
            {
                // Attach event handler to packet-received event.
                outgauge.PacketReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {

                    Console.Clear();

                    //String command = 'S' + speed.ToString("D3") + '\r';
                    int speed = Convert.ToInt32(e.Speed * 3.6);
                    int rpm = Convert.ToInt32(e.RPM);
                    String command = "S " + speed.ToString("D3") + "\r" + "R " + rpm.ToString("D4") + "\r";
                    Console.Write(command);
                    serialport.Write(command);


                };
                outgauge.TimedOut += outgauge_TimedOut;

                // Start listening for packets from LFS.
                outgauge.Connect("127.0.0.1", 30001);

                // Stop program from exiting while listening.
                Console.ReadLine();

            }

            serialport.Close();
        }
        static void outgauge_TimedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OutGauge timed out!");
        }

    }
}
```

And arduino code:

```
#include <Messenger.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#define LCD_LINES 2
#define LCD_ROWS 16


Messenger message;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void sendVersion()
{
  Serial.println(F("AD 01.12 ArduDash"));
}

void sendOK()
{
  Serial.println(F("OK"));
}

void sendERROR()
{
  Serial.println(F("ERROR"));
}

void setSpeedLCD(int speed)
{
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd_rjust_number(speed, 3);
  lcd.print(F(" km/h"));
}

void setSpeed()
{
  int speed = message.readInt();
  if (speed < 3 || speed > 230)
  {
    sendERROR();

    speed=0;
  }

  //setSpeedServo(speed);
  setSpeedLCD(speed);
  sendOK();
}

void lcd_rjust_number(int num, byte length)
{
  if (num < 10)
  {
    lcd.print(F(" "));
  }

  if (num < 100)
  {
    lcd.print(F(" "));
  }

  if (num < 1000 && length == 4)
  {
    lcd.print(F(" "));
  }

  lcd.print(num);
}

void setRPM()
{
  int rpm = message.readInt();
  if (rpm > 10000 || rpm < 0)
  {
    sendERROR();
    return;
  }

  setRPMLCD(rpm);
  sendOK();
}

void setRPMLCD(int rpm)
{
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  byte progress_width = map(rpm, 0, 10000, 0, 10);
  for (byte x=0; x<10; x++)
  {
    if (x < progress_width)
    {
      lcd.print(F("#"));
    }

    else
    {
      lcd.print(F(" "));
    }
  }

  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd_rjust_number(rpm, 4);
}

void onMessage()
{
  switch (message.readChar())
  {
    case 'S':
      setSpeed();
      break;
    case 'R':
      setRPM();
      break;
  }
  Serial.flush();
}

void serialEvent()
{
  message.process(Serial.read());
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  message.attach(onMessage);
  lcd.begin(LCD_ROWS, LCD_LINES);

}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing SeriarlEvent code to

```
while ( Serial.available() )  message.process(Serial.read () );
```